# Websphere j2ee app profiling like xhprof for PHP

Tags: jakarta-ee, profiling, websphere, xhprof

I have used xhprof in php web app for profiling web request.

xhprof shows nice callgraph with amount of time spent on specific method etc.

I want to do similar thing for j2ee app in websphere.

Do j2ee/websphere have any profiling library/plugin similar to xhprof?

Answer (score 0):

Many java profilers work, one of the simplest ways to get started with profiling an application inside websphere is to check out health center:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/1208_hare/1208_hare.html#N101DB